# Set an event on item select CheckboxList

Tags: asp.net

How to fire an event based on selected item in Checkboxlist (ASP.net 3.5), the OnSelectedIndexChanged in Checkboxlist returns a list of all the selected items, where I need to know just the current selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't a checkbox list return all of the checkboxes selected?  The nature of a checkbox list is that multiple can be selected at the same time.

If you desired only a single item, perhaps a radioButtonList or DropDownList would be more appropriate?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd7hsyy(v=VS.85).aspx

```
Protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
     System.EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = "You selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Feel free to test CheckBoxList.SelectedItem, but the wording does not clearly indicate that it has the same functionality as RadioButtonList or DropDownList.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx

Comment: Both inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl and could share this functionality. CheckBoxList may also be the wrong choice of ListControl.